# What it is the jQuery equivalent function of Javascript DafaultValue()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get the default value of an input textbox when the page was loaded. As I searched around I saw that the `DefaultValue()` is a method to get a value from a textbox when is loaded . But what is the jQuery one?

```
<input id=text > </input>

<script>
$(#text).DefaultValue(); // This is wrong I need the Jquery function of this
</script>
```

Any Idea?

Comment: `$(#text)` is invalid. Also I'm pretty sure it should be `defaultValue()`, not `DefaultValue()`.

Comment: I will edit my mistakes.Sorry

Comment: $(#text).val(); should do the work.

Comment: Your code is not wrong because jQuery is missing `DefaultValue()`. It's wrong because there is no `DefaultValue()` function in Javascript. There is however the `defaultValue` property which you can use natively in Javascript or by using `prop()` in jQuery.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can read the `defaultValue` DOM property like this:

```
$('#text').prop('defaultValue')
```

Heres a working example

```js
$('#value').click(function(){
    alert($('#text').val())  
});

$('#def').click(function(){
    alert($('#text').prop("defaultValue"))  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="text" value="This is the default value">
<button id="value">Click to see the current value</button>
<button id="def">Click to see the default value</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to call a Javascript DOM function on a jQuery object, you can simple extract the corresponding DOM object with `.get(0)` or `[0]`:

```
$("#text").get(0).defaultValue;
$("#text")[0].defaultValue;
```

Note also that you were calling the basic JS wrong. First, it's `defaultValue`, not `DefaultValue`. Second, it's a property, not a method, so there's no parentheses after it.

Comment: I think he _need the Jquery function of this._

Comment: There is no DOM method `DefaultValue`.

Comment: There is no jQuery function that does this. So you use the function that returns the DOM object and then call the normal Javascript function.

Comment: Yes, but `DefaultValue` is not it! Javascript methods generally start with a lowercase character

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$(function(){
    console.log($('#text')[0].defaultValue);
    // or try
    console.log($('#text').prop( 'defaultValue' )); 
});
```

Read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement